# Could not instantiate dialect class NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I am using Visual Studio 2005 with NHibernate-2.1.2.GA in Windows Server 2003.

I try to connect oracle with NHibernate in my ASP.net program.

To get the version of my oracle, i run this SQL : `select * from v$version`

The result show the oracle version is `oracle9i`.

So, I write `NHibernate.cfg.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
          Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
          (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYORACLE)));
          user id=team;password=team;
        </property>
        <property name="adonet.batch_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
        <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
        <property name="command_timeout">10</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
          NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,
          NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
        </property>
        <mapping assembly="NHibernateSample.Domain"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Now, when I run the test unit which try to connect oracle and excute a query sql :

```
 private ISession _session;
    private SessionManager _helper;
    private NHibernateSample _sample;
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
     {
            _helper = new SessionManager();
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            _session = _helper.GetSession();
            _sample = new NHibernateSample(_session);
        }
        [NUnit.Framework.Test]
        public void GetCustomerById1Test()
        {
            TestFixtureSetup();
            Setup();
            NHibernateSample _sample = new NHibernateSample(_session);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, _sample.GetCustomerById(1).Id);
        }
```

it reports errors like the following:

```
Test 'NHibernateSample.Data.Test.NHibernateSampleFixture.GetCustomerById1Test' failed: NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: NHibernateSample.Domain.Mappings.Customer.hbm.xml
  ----> NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not instantiate dialect class NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect
  ----> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type org.NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.
```

I know that this is beginner's issue but I am just a newbie! I appreciate your ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Try again removing `org.` from `dialect`

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
```

Check [NHibernate SQL Dialects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects) from official documentation for more details.

Comment: @user1201399: so now the error is `System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect` right? Which NHibernate version are you using?

Comment: yeah,the result is like what you say.My NHibernate Version is NHibernate-2.1.2.GA

Comment: @user1201399: are you referencing Oracle.DataAccess.dll? It doesn't sound to me that this dll can cause this problem but let's cover every option...

Comment: I add reference to System.Data.OracleClient in my project and add " using System.Data.OracleClient" if  .cs file. The result is the same!

Comment: what about `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`?

Comment: But I can't find Oracle.DataAccess.dll in my Server.By the way,The Oracle isn't install by me.Someone install PLSQL Developer in the Server.Actually,I don't know the relationship between PLSQL Developer and Oracle.Too bad!This issue drive me crazy!

Comment: @user1201399: check if this post helps in some way http://nhbwithoracle.blogspot.com.ar/

Comment: Link is down, could you provide another one?

Comment: @Joel: upgraded link

Answer (score 0):

Thanks God,Finally I fix this problem.
Thers is a message in result which i forget to paste above,it's like this:

```
未能从程序集“mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089”中加载类型“System.DateTimeOffset”
```

It's caused because my .Net2.0 version is old.
Then i install .Net2.0 SP1 and the probelm is fixed!
Thanks Claudio Redi all the same!